# Is there an option to add S3 Storage to Windows?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage

Im asking if there is an option to add S3 Storage to Windows? It should be something without a third party software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, S3 is not block storage, so it can't be directly mounted by an operating system. There are some third party tools that implement this, but in my experience they don't work very well.

---

Edit: It looks like [Amazon does have a solution](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/mounting-amazon-s3-to-an-amazon-ec2-instance-using-a-private-connection-to-s3-file-gateway/) for this now.

Comment: You might have a documentation or sth. for that? I haven‘t found anything that would work without 3rd Party Software.

Comment: See my edit, I did find a first-party solution. But if you want to look at third party solutions just do a search for "mount s3 on windows" in a search engine and you will find lots of results.